# Rails: Creating a form where user specifies association and one that is based on current resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an article model and a comment model. I currently have two separate forms to create new comments: one that allows the user to specify the name of the article their comment is for and a one underneath an article show view that creates new comments for that article. I am using form_for @comment in the first case and form_for [@article, @comment] in the second case. When a user specifies an article name as a string I convert it to an article id before saving the comment.

My routes are

```
resources :comments

resources :articles do
  resources :comments 
end
```

For the second form how can I redirect back to the article on a failed comment save (validations and errors should be displayed)? For the first form I just redirect to the homepage as that is where my first comment form is.

Also, I have a validation on the first form that the article name field cannot be empty. How can I remove this validation for the second form as the user does not need to specify an article name?

My new function in the comments_controller handles both forms. How do I determine which form is being submitted in the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually redirecting isn't the way to go here, I'd say. Error and validation handling in Rails usually works the way that you re-render the form in the `create` or `update` method with the validated object(s) instead of actually redirecting to the `new` or `edit` page.

As for your problem with the two versions of comments saving, I would use `form_for @comment` in both versions. Dump the nested form version simulate the user's behavior with the given article string in your form. This way you could spare a lot of if-else statements.

As for the rendering on validation errors part, you could simply check if you have an article_id in your params (which means your creating/updating a comment through a given article) or not (which means you have the first version).

Some code to elaborate:

```
# routes.rb
# keep the routes as they are
resources :comments
resources :articles
  resources :comments
end

# CommentsController.rb
def new
  # don't use build
  @comment = Comment.new

  # get the article, if there is one to get
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id]) if params[:article_id]

  # get all articles if there is no single one to get
  @articles = Article.all unless params[:article_id]
end

def create
  # fetch article id from title (in any case)
  # I'm assuming here
  params[:comment][:article_id] = fetch_article_id_from_title(params[:comment][:article_title])

  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to everything_worked_fine_path
  else
    # render the new view of the comments and actually
    #  forget the article view. Most sites do it like this
    render action: "new"
  end
end

# form partial
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <% if @article %>
    # there's an article to save this comment for
    <%= f.hidden_field :article_title, @article.title   # I'm assuming here
  <% else %>
    # this means there's no particular article present, so let's
    # choose from a list
    <%= f.select ... %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if you were doing this just for the explicitness of this explanation, but you can also shortcut your *render action: "new"* call to just *render :new*